# Point on an algebraic surface closest to another one

Tags: algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods

Given an algebraic surface $F(x,y,z)=0$, $F\in\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, and a point $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, is there a possibility to (algorithmically) determine a point on $F(x,y,z)=0$ that is closest to $P_0$ with respect to the Euclidean distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can combine algebraic techniques with Lagrange multipliers.

More precisely, you want to minimize the function $$D(x,y,z)=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2$$ subject to $F(x,y,z)=0$. To do this, introduce an additional variable $\lambda$, and solve the two equations $\nabla(F)=\lambda \nabla D$ and $F(x,y,z)=0$. So you have four equations in four unknowns, all algebraic equations.

To find solutions, you could use Gröbner basis techniques, which are implemented in for example Macaulay2.

Comment: This seems to work. But what do you mean with polynomial division? There is also a typo (two four -> four)

Comment: @porst17 Thank you for the comment. I deleted the comment about polynomial division, as it is not clear how to do polynomial division with several equations (just think of Gröbner basis computations instead). I've corrected the typo, thank you.